# Sidekiq worker didn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, notifications, sidekiq

I tried to setup a basic notification worker to notify some user.
But in my example my user didn't get any notifcation.

my controller action where I tried to perform my worker:

```
  def index
    NotificationWorker.delay().perform(current_user.id, 'error', 'refresh', 'test', 'asd')
    # ActionCable.server.broadcast "web_notifications_#{current_user.id}", { type: 'error', icon: 'refresh', title: 'title', body: 'body' }
  end
```

my notification_worker.rb

```
class NotificationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id, type, icon, title, body)
    Notification.create(user_id, type, icon, title, body)
  end
end
```

and my notification model:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  # belongs_to
  belongs_to :users

  def self.create(user_id, type, icon, title, body)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "web_notifications_#{user_id}", { type: 'error', icon: 'refresh', title: 'title', body: 'body' }
  end
end
```

when I use this

```
Notification.create(current_user.id, 'error', 'refresh', 'test', 'asd')
```

my user get the notification but I wan't to send them with sidekiq

Comment: do you have sidekiq running?

Comment: nope, that was the Problem :(

Comment: Don't do `NotificationWorker.delay().perform`, do `NotificationWorker.perform_async`

Comment: @MikePerham why I should use `NotificationWorker.perform_async` and not `NotificationWorker.delay().perform`?

Comment: Because that's not `delay`s intended usage.  Please read the docs. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/The-Basics#client  Delay is for calling class methods on classes. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions#class-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my assumption in comments - the issue was that you did not run the sidekiq.